# How to get the timestamp of a specific previous/last time with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime, momentjs

The following gives me the timestamp of the current date-time:

Source

```
moment().utc().valueOf()
```

Output

```
1626964579209 // 2021-07-22T14:36:19Z
```

***How do I get the timestamp of the previous/last 07:00 AM (2021-07-22T07:00:00Z) and 11:00 PM (2021-07-21T23:00:00Z) date-times?***

Notice that, in this situation, the last/previous 11:00 PM timestamp is from the previous day (2021-07-21).

I've tried playing around with Moment.js [Durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) and [Subtract Time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/) but without much success.

Here's a StackBlitz to play around: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ofcrjs

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zvmpqb

Comment: @dave it looks like you found a proper solution! If you post your solution as an answer I'll accept it as the solution for this problem. Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```js
const currentDateTime = moment().utc();
console.log('Current date-time timestamp:', currentDateTime.valueOf());
console.log('Current date-time string:', currentDateTime.format());

// If the current date-time string is 2021-07-22T14:36:19Z
// then the previous/last 07:00 AM string is 2021-07-22T07:00:00Z and the
// previous/last 11:00 PM string is 2021-07-21T23:00:00Z (previous day)
let last7amTimestamp = currentDateTime.clone().startOf('d').add(7, 'h'); // ???
if (last7amTimestamp.isAfter(currentDateTime)) {
  last7amTimestamp.subtract(1, 'd')
}
let last11pmTimestamp = currentDateTime.clone().startOf('d').add(23, 'h'); // ???
if (last11pmTimestamp.isAfter(currentDateTime)) {
  last11pmTimestamp.subtract(1, 'd')
}

console.log('Previous/last 07:00 AM timestamp:', last7amTimestamp);
console.log('Previous/last 11:00 PM timestamp:', last11pmTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?

```
moment('7:00 AM', 'h:mm A').subtract(1,'days').utc().valueOf();
moment('11:00 PM', 'hh:mm A').subtract(1,'days').utc().valueOf();
```

Just get the  time of today and subtract day by 1.

Comment: Hi @văn-vi that's a good start but you're subtracting a day no matter what. There needs to be a way to check or set if those times are from the current day or from the last day. It looks like dave found a proper solution. Thanks a lot anyway for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can test the current UTC hour and if it's after the required hour, just set the UTC hour to the time. If it's before, set it to the hour on the previous day, i.e. hour - 24.

E.g. a general function to get the previous specified hour UTC given a supplied date or default to the current date without moment.js is:

```js
// Get the previous hour UTC given a Date
// Default date is current date
function previousUTCHour(h, d = new Date()) {
  // Copy d so don't affect original
  d = new Date(+d);
  return d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() < h ? h - 24 : h, 0, 0, 0);
}

// Example
let d = new Date();
console.log('Currently : ' + d.toISOString());
[1, 7, 11, 18, 23].forEach(
  h => console.log('Previous ' + (''+h).padStart(2, '0') +
       ' ' + new Date(previousUTCHour(h)).toISOString())
);
```